# 500.21 internal serve error bad module has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler

we have a website which runs under v4.0 , Classic Mode. We have recently created new httphandler and when we request to this handler we receive 
500.21 internal serve error - bad module has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list.

WebSite works fine with no issues.  I have tried all possible solution given in google like regiis & add entry of handler to system.webserver but nothing has worked for me.

Can someone give some idea on the same?

Comment: Looks like you have set preCondition of handler as managedHandler in web.config. Instead you should set it as ISAPIMode as you are running app pool in clasic mode.

Comment: @PankajKapare I didnt set precondition for my handler. Btw how do I set as ISAPI Mode?.

Comment: In web.config file search for your handler  and add attribute preCondition="ISAPIMode" there in handler configuration.

Comment: @PankajKapare No it doesnt works.   here is how my handler looks -<add name="LockAutomationCallback" verb="POST" path="callbackservice.lockautomationapi" type="Handlers.LockAutomationHandler" preCondition="ISAPIMode" />

Comment: @PankajKapare it got worked when I change precondition for ISAPIModule to 4.0 from 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command, which will install and register ASP.NET 4.5 in IIS:

dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all